# Python Type Error when trying to create new column in DataFrame using conditional logic against two existing date columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Below is my **Data Frame**; I'm trying to **create a new column** (Planned_Current_Month) using conditional logic against two existing date columns:

[Data Frame Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7xeD.jpg)

I have attempted to do this using the code below in **Python** (utilising **Pandas** & **Numpy**):

```
__current_month = pd.datetime.now().month
__current_year = pd.datetime.now().year

df['Planned_Current_Month'] = \
    np.where(df.Date1.dt.month == __current_month
             & df.Date1.dt.year == __current_year
             & (df.Date2.dt.month.isnull()
             | (df.Date2.dt.month >= __current_month
             & df.Date2.dt.year == __current_year)), 1, 0)
```

I am getting the **error** below:

*TypeError: Cannot perform 'rand_' with a dtyped [float64] array and scalar of type [bool]*

What is it complaining about? Is there a better, more efficient way to create this column? I am relatively new to Python/Pandas/Numpy so help, guidance, and tips would be appreciated.

August is used in the example as the current month.

Added Dataset as requested:

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------------------+
|   Date1   |   Date2   | Planned_Current_Month |
+-----------+-----------+-----------------------+
| 10-Aug-20 |           |                     1 |
| 29-Feb-20 |           |                     0 |
| 16-Mar-20 | 20-Apr-20 |                     0 |
| 07-Aug-20 | 06-Jul-20 |                     0 |
| 28-Aug-20 | 18-Aug-20 |                     1 |
| 22-Jul-20 | 05-Aug-20 |                     0 |
+-----------+-----------+-----------------------+
```

Comment: Could you add your dataset as plain text rather than an image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code in python 3.7.7 with numpy 1.19.1 and your sample dataset and it's working. However, you need to add some parenthesis:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["10-Aug-20",""],
["29-Feb-20",""],
["16-Mar-20","20-Apr-20"],
["07-Aug-20","06-Jul-20"],
["28-Aug-20","18-Aug-20"],
["22-Jul-20","05-Aug-20"]], columns = ["Date1","Date2"])

df["Date1"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date1"])
df["Date2"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date2"])

__current_month = 8
__current_year = 2020

df['Planned_Current_Month'] = \
    np.where((df.Date1.dt.month == __current_month) \
             & (df.Date1.dt.year == __current_year) \
             & ((df.Date2.dt.month.isnull() )\
             | ((df.Date2.dt.month >= __current_month) \
             & (df.Date2.dt.year == __current_year))), 1, 0)
```

Output:

```
    Date1       Date2       Planned_Current_Month
0   2020-08-10  NaT         1
1   2020-02-29  NaT         0
2   2020-03-16  2020-04-20  0
3   2020-08-07  2020-07-06  0
4   2020-08-28  2020-08-18  1
5   2020-07-22  2020-08-05  0
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help :). If there is a better/more efficient way to do this please do let me know. All the best.